# Update Script in SQL Server to add a hyphen after 5 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I have a `varchar` column which has data like `ABCDE1`, the first five characters will be alphanumeric.

I would like to add a hyphen for all records after fifth character

```
ABCDE-1
```

How can I achieve using an update script in SQL Server?

Comment: You write code. Start by reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms181984.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`STUFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188043.aspx) function

```
Select STUFF(varchar_col,5+1,0,'-')
From yourtable
```

To Update

```
Update yourtable Set varchar_col = STUFF(varchar_col,5+1,0,'-')
```